# How add watermark on ts video?

Tags: video, cmd, ffmpeg

How add watermark on ts video?
After adding a watermark to the video (ts format) using the command below, output video (ts format too) does not playing in the browser
What could be the reason for this?

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay=790:40 -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset superfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -y output.ts
```

Comment: Could the ts file be played in a browser before? I don't think browsers support that mime type.

Comment: What happens if you use doublequotes around the string which includes the `=` character? i.e. `"overlay=790:40"`

Comment: @Compo tried like this, same thing

Comment: @zero298 Yes, everything works through hls player before adding watermark

Comment: Is there any error message from the browser? Which browser and version?

Comment: @lit No errors.
This is a stream (m3u8 file) and after adding a watermark, the stream freezes after 5-7 seconds, without adding a watermark everything works without problems

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the 'copyts' flag solved my problem

Comment: Where did you add the copyts flag? Can you please show the full command? @r_astapov

Comment: Nevermind I was using "copyts" instead of "-copyts"